# How to add keys with expiry to Redis in batch mode?

Tags: python, redis, pipeline, batch-processing

I need to add multiple key/values in batch mode to Redis with expiry time.

My Python code to add multiple key/values to Redis looks like this:

```
r = redis.Redis()
pipe = r.pipeline()

for i in range(10):
  pipe.set('p' + str(i), i)
  
pipe.execute()
```

How can I add the keys with expiry time so that when I query for keys, the expired keys should not be included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Redis client function ['set'](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#core-commands) , add a parameter 'ex' with expiry time in seconds.

```
r = redis.Redis() pipe = r.pipeline()

for i in range(10): pipe.set('p' + str(i), i, **ex=120**)

pipe.execute()
```